# dvgrab error: driver recieved an incomplete frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera

I am unable to use my DV webcam:

```
 # dvgrab -input /dev/video1 

 Waiting for DV...
    End of pipe

    "": frame dropped: timecode 00:00:00.00 date 1999.11.30 00:00:00
    This error means that the ieee1394 driver received an incomplete frame.
```

**What is the origin of this error?**

It seems like a module within a package is missing. I cannot start ieee1394:

```
  modprobe ieee1392
   moddprobe: FATAL: Module aa not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-amd64
```